# jboss-5.1.0.GA auto start on boot

Tags: jboss5.x, ubuntu-10.04

I was given the task of installing jboss-5.1.0.GA on a remote ubuntu 10.4 Lts server.  With all those resources out there I was able to run jboss successfully but my problem was that I wasn't able to get auto start on boot work so that jboss would be running on the server.

I followed a couple of tutorials that said me create a separate user called jboss and to copy the jboss_init_Redhat.sh to the /etc/init.d/jboss (jboss home, java path ,jboss user and the binding to 0.0.0.0 is all set) and used /etc/init.d/jboss start

but I can't get to see the Jboss page at the Ip on a browser.,

If i do a `./run.sh -b 0.0.0.0 ==>` the server is up ...

Can some body shed some light on this issue????

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run JBoss AS on given interface using `jboss_init_redhat.sh` script look at these line:

```
#if JBOSS_HOST specified, use -b to bind jboss services to that address
JBOSS_BIND_ADDR=${JBOSS_HOST:+"-b $JBOSS_HOST"}
```

You should just define new variable **before** these line:

```
JBOSS_HOST="0.0.0.0"
```

You should also check shutdown command (especially when you run your server on some other address then 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0), it should know how to find your server:

```
JBOSS_CMD_STOP=${JBOSS_CMD_STOP:-"java -classpath $JBOSSCP org.jboss.Shutdown --shutdown -s jnp://${JBOSS_HOST}:1099"}
```

Comment: i addded the bind address like this
JBOSS_BIND_ADDR=${JBOSS_HOST:+-"-b 0.0.0.0"}